# admin can not change author profile picture

Tags: capabilities, profiles

i logged in as Administrator in my WordPress dashboard but i can not get any option to change authors profile picture, i can change profile cover image but no option for profile so, anyone have any idea please share..

Comment: are you using any plugin for cover picture and profile picture? generally profile picture is generated by Gravetor.

Comment: Please provide your plugins list. BTW: Wordpress does not have any in-build profile cover image like Facebook so you can not change it from wp-admin.